# Extract attachments from email and email them as attachments using win32com.client in Python

Tags: python-3.x, email, outlook, email-attachments, office-automation

I am trying to loop through email messages in Outlook using python and get all the attachments in each email, extract them and send them to a different person if it meets a certain criteria. Currently I am saving the attachment and re-attaching it while sending an email. Is there any way where I can do this dynamically and not save the file in the first place

Here is what I have:

```
import os 
import win32com.client
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)

messages = inbox.Items
messages.Sort("[ReceivedTime]", True)
first_msg = messages.GetFirst()

attachments = first_msg.Attachments
attachment = attachments[0]
attachment.SaveAsFile(os.getcwd()+'\\'+attachment.filename)

Outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
mail = Outlook.CreateItem(0)

mail.To = 'email@test.com'
mail.Subject = 'This is a sample'
attachment = mail.Attachments.Add(myfolder/file.pdf)
mail.Body = 'Sending an attachment through email using python'
mail.Send()
```

Is there a method where I can bypass saving the file and send the attached file directly?

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide any method or property for dealing with attachments on the fly (without saving them to a disk). The [Attachment.SaveAsFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachment.saveasfile) method which saves the attachment to the specified path is exactly what you need.

On the other side you may consider a low-level API on which Outlook is built on - Extended MAPI. It allows opening getting property values with streams without saving them to the disk. The `PR_ATTACH_DATA_BIN` property holds the attachment when the value of the `PR_ATTACH_METHOD` property is `ATTACH_BY_VALUE`, which is the usual attachment method and the only one required to be supported. `PR_ATTACH_DATA_BIN` also holds an OLE 1.0 OLESTREAM attachment when the value of `PR_ATTACH_METHOD` is ATTACH_OLE. See [Opening an attachment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/opening-an-attachment) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Not in the Outlook Object Model - saving the attachment as file (if it is a regular `olByValue` attachment) and reattaching it is your only option. You can attach the whole original message as an attachment though by passing a `MailItem` object as an argument to `Attachments.Add`: that will create an embedded message attachment.

As Eugene suggested, you can use Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi), but it is not accessible in Python. If using [Redemption](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption) is an option (I am its author), it allows to pass one attachment (`RDOAttachment`) as an argument to `RDOMail.Attachments.Add` without saving as file first. That will work for all types of attachments (`olByValue`, `olOLE`, `olEmbeddedItem`, etc.)